# Python Ask For Decimal Number

Tags: python, decimal

Can someone please tell me how to get the code to ask for a value (say the user would enter 100.00) and put that number with it's 2 decimal points value for more functions later on, ie: multipling it, etc.

Thanks.

Comment: This typo of question is most certainly doomed to failure. We will not do your (home)work for you. Read a [tutorial](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/), try something yourself, and come back when you have a specific problem.

Comment: Thank you for your concern, I am having trouble with returning 2 zero values, ie for 100.00
I am googling away still, but am having trouble finding this, hence why I am asking a forum.

Comment: Stop googling and post your code, please.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's a start (for Python 3; for Python 2, use `raw_input` instead of `input`):

```
while True:
    snum = input("Please enter a decimal number:")
    try:
        num = float(snum)
        break
    except ValueError:
        print("This is not a valid decimal number!")
print("This number, rounded to two places, is: {:0.2f}".format(num))
```

Comment: When I put in 100.00 the return value I get is 100.0
Is there a way to show both zero values please?

Comment: Now wait a second. Do you want to round the number (possibly changing it), or do you just want to restrict the output to two decimal places, leaving the number itself unchanged?

Comment: I don't want to edit the value at all. I just want 100.00 to return as 100.00, not as 100.0 as it is at the moment.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following in python shell.

```
>>> int(100.00)
100
>>>
```